# Is there a command to show all active game rules?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

A command that would show all the active and inactive gamerules;;
Ie:: `keepInventory`, `mobGreifing`, `doFireTick`, `doMobSpawning`, `doTileDrops`, ect.

That way I can tell which are on and off//true or false.

I was looking through the MC wiki to find one such command and didn't see one. I'm not sure if I missed it or not, and I don't really wanna read through the page a third time. XD

If there isn't, there totally should be.

SIDE QUESTION:?:*When any such game rule is turned on via redstone÷lever when the signal is sent it's activated, but will flicking the lever off deactivate the command?
And the same with buttons, but is it deactivated after pressing it a second time?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no command to list all active and inactive gamerules, but you can do `/gamerule (gamerule)` to determine if the gamerule is true or false. Sorry.

Agreed, there totally should be a command for this.

Side Question Answer: The gamerule will be set to whatever boolean you supply in `/gamerule (gamerule) (boolean)` no matter how many times you flick the lever or press the button. You can do something like this to produce the desired effect though:

S-R-C-T-C

(S = source, R = repeater, C = command block, T = torch (positioned on the 1st command block)

Command block 1 would have `/gamerule (gamerule) true`, and #2 would have `/gamerule (gamerule) false`. When the source is powered, gamerule would be true -- when it's not, gamerule would be false.

Comment: I right same, but that'll have to do for now I suppose. However I did test to see if `/gamerule (gamerule)` would toggle the command in the when using the block, and it didn't seem to work that way. But I may have messed it up somehow. ^ ^;

Comment: Perhaps toggling doesn't work in command blocks, I was too anxious to post my first answer to wait until today to get on Minecraft and check. :) I'll check ASAP tomorrow, and report back to you.

Comment: Wow <derp>. You can't do /gamerule (gamerule). I must have been tired. Editting now...

Comment: I supplied you a mini-circuit to produce the desired effect.